# Everything on my screen just became large after restarting

Tags: lightdm, display-resolution

I just installed Ubuntu yesterday and this is my first time using Linux. I was trying to change the greeter from gdm3 to lightdm to enable guest logins. I restarted the computer to check if lightdm was working. It was, but everything became so large. I tried to change the resolution but it was blurry, nothing like what I was seeing previously. I also tried to change back the greeter to gdm3, but nothing happened.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. My computer's processor is amd a8 7600 and it has no dedicated graphics card. I don't know if this is contributing to the problem, but I am dual booting it with windows 7.

Another thing I noticed is that even the grub bootloader's resolution became larger.

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using, what graphics adapter do you have, what computer model?  This looks like fallback graphics mode -- any error messages during startup?

Comment: Check your screen settings and see if magnification is set greater than 1.0

Comment: I haven't had any error messages during startup, just the normal grub bootloader

Comment: Still normal in Windows?

Comment: Yes it's still normal in windows 7

Comment: I just opened my pc and was surprised that the screen is finally back to normal. I didn't know what happened, I just went to bed the other night with everything large on my screen.